# Google auth, next.js, next-auth, can not set cookie in signIn callback

Tags: next.js, cookies, next-auth

In my signIn callback function, I'm making an API POST request to the backend for user login and registration. Once the backend processes the login and registration, it sends a response containing a token, this token will be used later as accessToken for fetching the backend data (Laravel), in my code set this token as let myToken = response.data.token. Then, I'm trying to set it in cookies, but unfortunately, it's not working as expected. Can someone assist me with this issue? Here's my code for reference

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { Account } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import axios from "axios";
import {serialize} from "cookie";

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID =
  "*************";
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "************";
const FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID = "************";
const FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET = "********";
interface Profile {
  email: string;
  id: number;
}
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin

      if (account) {
        token.id_token = account.id_token;
      }
      console.log("JWT Callback:", token);
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      //@ts-ignore
      session.id_token = token.id_token;
      //@ts-ignore
      return session;
    },
    //@ts-ignore
    async signIn({ account, profile }: { account: Account; profile: Profile }) {
      if (!profile?.email) {
        console.log("no profile");
      }
      const provider = account.provider;
      // Declare a variable to store the ID
      let id = profile.id;

      // Check if the provider is facebook or google
      if (provider === "facebook") {
        id = profile.id;
      } else if (provider === "google") {
        // Get the Google ID from the account object
        //@ts-ignore
        id = account?.id_token;
      }

      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `http://localhost/api/v1/user/login/social`,
            //@ts-ignore
            {
              email: profile.email,
              id: id,
              provider: provider,
              //@ts-ignore
              name: profile.name,
            },
        );
        let myToken = response.data.token;
        //Set token expiration time (current 3 days)
        const MAX_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;

        //Pass the token to be set in the cookie
        const serialized = serialize("OutSiteJWT", myToken, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV == "production",
          sameSite: "strict",
          maxAge: MAX_AGE,
          path: "/",
        });

        //Set the return message
        //Return the message to client
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({message:"Token saved"}), {
          status: 200,
          headers: { "Set-Cookie": serialized },
        });
      } catch (error: any) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export default authOptions;
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I'm trying to set it in cookies, but unfortunately, it's not working as expected.